# <Access Denied> for WiFi Controller

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

After a recent update the "Enable Wifi" disappeared completely and when I run `sudo lshw -C network` it says this for my network card controller:

```
      *-network               
           description: Network controller
           product: Wireless 3160
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
           version: 83
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
           configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
           resources: irq:48 memory:b2600000-b2601fff
      *-network
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
           logical name: eth0
           version: 0c
           serial: a0:1d:48:c2:a9:81
           size: 100Mbit/s
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.1.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
           resources: irq:43 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2500000-b2500fff memory:b2400000-b2403fff
      *-network:0
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: 3
           logical name: veth7f789d6
           serial: 92:92:e6:a9:3e:08
           capabilities: ethernet physical
           configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
      *-network:1
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: 4
           logical name: veth46c0b81
           serial: 7a:57:ea:9d:f0:82
           capabilities: ethernet physical
           configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
      *-network:2
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: 5
           logical name: vethae6defe
           serial: 42:95:94:2c:b8:4f
           capabilities: ethernet physical
           configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

Comment: That doesn't mean *"<Access Denied> for WiFi Controller"* it just means *Access denied to show the capabilities of the wifi controller to an unprivileged user* - try running `lspci` again with `sudo`

Comment: Your first command looks like you ran it with the `-v`.  The second time you ran it with the `sudo` you left the `-v` off.

Comment: The wifi is clearly shown: Intel 3160.

Comment: +1 if you want detailed network device information I'd suggest either `sudo lspci -vnn | grep -A12 '\[02.0\]'` or `sudo lshw -C network`